# Matching value with column to retrieve index value

Tags: python, pandas

Please see example dataframe below:
I'm trying match values of columns X with column names and retrieve value from that matched column

so that:

```
A B C X result
1 2 3 B 2 
5 6 7 A 5
8 9 1 C 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What would your desired output look like in this case? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi,
My aim is to get the "result" columns as shown above.
I've played around with np.where and .loc combinations without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of methods:

```
# Apply Method:
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name, x['X']], axis=1)

# List comprehension Method:
df['result'] = [df.loc[i, x] for i, x in enumerate(df.X)]

# Pure Pandas Method:
df['result'] = (df.melt('X', ignore_index=False)
                  .loc[lambda x: x['X'].eq(x['variable']), 'value'])
```

Comment: Thanks! ended up using "Apply Method"

Answer (score 0):

Here I just build a dataframe from your example and call it `df`

```
dict = {
    'A': (1,5,8),
    'B': (2,6,9),
    'C': (3,7,1),
    'X': ('B','A','C')}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

You can extract the value from another column based on 'X' using the following code. There may be a better way to do this without having to convert first to list and retrieving the first element.

`list(df.loc[df['X'] == 'B', 'B'])[0]`

I'm going to create a column called 'result' and fill it with 'NA' and then replace the value based on your conditions. The loop below, extracts the value and uses .loc to replace it in your dataframe.

```
df['result'] = 'NA'
for idx, val in enumerate(list(vals)):
    extracted = list(df.loc[df['X'] == val, val])[0]
    df.loc[idx, 'result'] = extracted
```

Here it is as a function:

```
def search_replace(dataframe, search_col='X', new_col_name='result'):
    dataframe[new_col_name] = 'NA'
    for idx, val in enumerate(list(vals)):
        extracted = list(dataframe.loc[dataframe[search_col] == val, val])[0]
        dataframe.loc[idx, new_col_name] = extracted
    return df
```

and the output

```
>>> search_replace(df)
    A   B   C   X   result
0   1   2   3   B   2
1   5   6   7   A   5
2   8   9   1   C   1
```

Comment: If you copy OP's dataframe, and just use `pd.read_clipboard()` you get nice output without having to manually make anything.

Comment: You got it! Happy to help.